# About non-existent tags

Tags: discussion, support, tags

Today I added "ganeti" to my favourite tags, but it does not exist as a tag. The UI allowed me to do that, I clicked on the tag and then on "About".

I got 404.

Is it a normal behaviour? I expected to see the tag wiki editing page or a page that told me that the tag does not exist and that I cannot create it (as I don't have the privileges).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems normal to me... This would allow you to make this tag a favorite now even if it doesn't exist yet, and then if it does exist later, you'll start following it.

The one thing I would suggest is that the 404 page, while *technically* correct (page not found because tag does not exist) might be confusing. Maybe the "about »" link shouldn't even show up if the tag is not created yet?
[image]

Comment: +1 IMHO it would be better if the about link didn't show.